# Use Cases for Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka

I have been learning about Kafka lately, in order to use the framework to send, receive, and store messages for our worker processes, using the python client (pykafka). Our messages are fairly short.

I understand that Kafka-Connect is in I/O of large amounts of data, but in what scenarios does it become better to use the Connect tool or not? How much data do you need to be sending/receiving for Kafka-Connect to be necessary? What are the features of Kafka-Connect that you believe are the most useful?

Also, what other frameworks or libraries do you use with Kafka?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Kafka Connect doesn't improve performance -- under the covers the Connect framework is using the producer and consumer API.

Connect is designed for connecting Kafka with other data systems, where minor key/value conversions (translations) are supported. The framework offers out-of-the-box fault tolerance and scalability. Many off-the-shelf connectors are already available (e.g. HDFS sink, JDBC source, many others). And if needed, you can build your own connector. You can learn more about Connect [here](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/intro.html).

Comment: One major difference between implementing a kafka producer/consumer vs writing a kafka connect "connector" would be the pull vs push model. With kafka connect, the connector would be pull the data from the source system while if we implement a custom kafka producer we would be pushing the data to kafka. If there many varied source systems it would be simpler to write kafka producers instead of having connector connect to remote system and fetch data. Is my understanding right?

Comment: It's freaking hard to debug with Kafka Connect, what a shame.

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential problems with Kafka connectors is that they are typically provided by 3rd parties, so you have to do some research to find and evaluate them to check if they are suitable for your purposes. However, they are potentially more robust and scalable than just a simple DIY consumer/producer pair. E.g. They have distributed workers for improved scalability and failover.

Here's a couple of blogs I've written that cover Kafka Connect that you may find useful.

- [Apache Kafka Connect Architecture Overview](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-kafka-connect-architecture-overview/)
- [Apache Kafka “Kongo” Part 4.1: Connecting Kafka to Cassandra with Kafka Connect](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-kafka-kongo-part-4-1-connecting-kafka-cassandra-kafka-connect/)
- [Apache Kafka “Kongo” Part 4.2: Connecting Kafka to Cassandra with
  Kafka Connect](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-kafka-kongo-part-4-2-connecting-kafka-cassandra-kafka-connect/)

Comment: Please provide essential details from link because links may get expire in future.

Answer (score 0):

kafka connect is generally use for synced operation. We can use this synched opeartion for files ,database etc. For Files synched opeartion you can refer below mentioned link.

https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/apache-kafka-connector/

In kafka connect we perform operation using two mode: 1. Standalone   2. Distributed

Standalone is used when we want to perform synched operation for files. Distributed is used when we want to perform synched operation for Database(We can synched two table present in two different database but columns of both table are of same type)

It contains two properties on the basis of which we perform operation :1. Source properties   2.Sink Properties
Eg. suppose if we want to perform operation on files then we made changes in this both properties and run command or using rest, using java code also we perform operation.
(In this properties we add name of the files and topic name prefixed with connect) Source file contains some data and when we run command :
**bin/windows/connect-standalone.bat config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties**

after running abovecommand it read the data from file mentioned in connect-file-source.properties. If not exist then it create the file.

•   Run consumer command to consume data from file

**.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning**

•   Run Below command to create Sink file

**bin/windows/connect-standalone.bat config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-source.properties**

In the end if we open our sink file and check the data we will able to see same data present in source file.

Similarly we made changes for tables synched operation using distributed mode by making the changes in Distributed.properties, JDBC source and sink propeerties

we can also perform synched opertaion using kafka-connect rest option.

Answer (score 0):

Writing code that reads data from **Kafka** and inserts it into a **database** takes maybe a day or two, but if you need to handle followings:

1. configuration
2. errors
3. REST APIs
4. monitoring
5. deployment
6. scaling up and down
7. handling failures

Then it can take a few months to get right. If you implement data copying with a **Kafka Connector**, your connector plugs into workers that handle a bunch of complicated operational issues (as aforementioned) that you don’t need to worry about.

**Reference Book:** Kafka: The Definitive Guide